# Does the Stack Overflow selection of job offerings work as intended?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Referring to the small box on the right hand side, which shows open positions. My guess was that they are selected somehow by criteria of my actions so far on stack overflow. Possibly (I am guessing here) related to the tags which were set for questions answered or asked or both.

**Potential issue 1:**

Now let us assume, that a person has a skill profile and an interest profile. Clearly, those two need not be identical. That is the first potential issue of the system. Anyone who would want to change to a new field of work but keeps answering questions which fall into the previous fields of expertise tempt the system to display "been there was there done with that" kinds of jobs.

**Potential issue 2**

The frequency of different tags showing up in questions is obviously not uniform. There are more popular tags than others. Let us assume now, a person has a skill profile, which comprises a few popular tags and comprises a few esoteric tags. Naturally (think of a lake with 2 kinds of fish with the ratio 100:1... you keep coming home from fishing with the frequent fish A and your wife assumes you like fish A and not fish B), the bulk of the actions the person performs here would relate to the popular tags, but this again might deprive the person to see job advertisements for the more esoteric tags, which in fact might be those of interest for the person.

I do not have any goals, writing this post here (don't request a change or so). The two points simply entered my mind and I am curious, what you guys think about them.

Comment: I could be way off about this, but I always assumed that the job recommendations were based off of previous searches on Stack Careers

Comment: Your question is very up to the point.... I would also like to know the answer...

Comment: I am getting a job offering for part time job in San Francisco. I am living in Europe though. On the other hand, another job offering is in my city and it actually matches my field. So some job offerings are good, some are really bad.

Comment: I always get "Want a `java` job?" and the `java` tag is not my favorite tag but the best tag of my profile.

Comment: Career questions like this have been migrated to Meta.SE before, see [the careers tag on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers)

Comment: @apaul34208 - I get shown job offers for mainly .Net positions close to my location; but I haven't really ever used the search on Careers.

Comment: Possibly related: [Personalization of Career Ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249745/273478)

Comment: What kinda also annoys me is that there are maybe 10 different jobs "close" by to me and now I see the same offerings all the time.

Comment: I just want to state that I really appreciated the lake scenario. +1